# How to plot solution of first order time dependent differential equations with other parameter not with time

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, parametric-functions

I am trying to plot the solution given in the code with respect to "delc", not w.r.t time "t". I don't know what to do for getting the plot between solution and value "delc" which vary 0 to 2. The initial condition are also included in the text. The only thing that i want is, plot between solution and "delc" for any arbitrary value of "t". If anyone can solve this is most welcome.

```
w1 = 1;
gma1 = 0.005;
n1 = 1;
  gma2 = 0.005;
  G1 = 0.005;
  k1 = .1;
k2 = 0.1;
a1 = 0.07;
a2 = 0.58;
k0 = 0.1;
Q1 = 1.268;
del0 = 1;
 N1 = 1;
    ome = 1;
     M1 = del0*(1 - Cos[ome*t]);
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{V11'[t] - V21[t]*w1 - V12[t]*w1 == 0, 
V12'[t] - V22[t]*w1 + w1*V11[t] + gma1*V12[t] - 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V13[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V14[t] == 0, 
V13'[t] - V23[t]*w1 + k1*V13[t] + 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V11[t] - (-G1*Q1 + delc)*V14[t] == 0, 
V14'[t] - V24[t]*w1 + k1*V14[t] - 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V11[t] - (G1*Q1 - delc)*V13[t] == 0, 
V21'[t] + V11[t]*w1 + gma1*V21[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V31[t] - 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V41[t] - w1*V22[t] == 0, 
V22'[t] + V12[t]*w1 + gma1*V22[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V32[t] - 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V42[t] + w1*V21[t] + gma1*V22[t] - 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V23[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V24[t] - gma2*(2*n1 + 1) ==
  0, V23'[t] + w1*V13[t] + gma1*V23[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V33[t] - 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V43[t] + k1*V23[t] + 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V21[t] - (-G1*Q1 + delc)*V24[t] == 0,
V24'[t] + V14[t]*w1 + gma1*V24[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V34[t] - 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V44[t] + k1*V24[t] - 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V21[t] - (G1*Q1 - delc)*V23[t] == 0, 
V31'[t] + k1*V31[t] + 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V11[t] - (-G1*Q1 + delc)*V41[t] - w1*V32[t] == 0, 
V32'[t] + k1*V32[t] + 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V12[t] - (-G1*Q1 + delc)*V42[t] + w1*V31[t] - 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V34[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V33[t] + gma1*V32[t] == 0, 
V33'[t] + k1*V33[t] + 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V13[t] - (-G1*Q1 + delc)*V43[t] + k1*V33[t] + 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V31[t] - (-G1*Q1 + delc)*V34[t] - k0 == 0, 
V34'[t] + k1*V34[t] + 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V14[t] - (-G1*Q1 + delc)*V44[t] + k1*V34[t] - 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V31[t] - (G1*Q1 - delc)*V33[t] == 0, 
V41'[t] + k1*V41[t] - 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V11[t] - (G1*Q1 - delc)*V31[t] - w1*V42[t] == 0, 
V42'[t] + k1*V42[t] + 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V12[t] - (G1*Q1 - delc)*V32[t] + w1*V41[t] - 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V44[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V43[t] + gma1*V42[t] == 0, 
V43'[t] + k1*V43[t] - 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V13[t] - (G1*Q1 - delc)*V33[t] + k1*V43[t] + 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V41[t] - (-G1*Q1 + delc)*V44[t] == 0, 
V44'[t] + k1*V44[t] - 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V14[t] - (G1*Q1 - delc)*V34[t] + k1*V44[t] - 
  Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V41[t] - (G1*Q1 - delc)*V43[t] - k0 == 0, 
V11[0] == 1, V12[0] == 1, V13[0] == 0, V14[0] == 0, V21[0] == 0, 
V22[0] == 1, V23[0] == 0, V24[0] == 0, V31[0] == 0, V32[0] == 0, 
V33[0] == 0, V34[0] == 0, V41[0] == 0, V42[0] == 0, V43[0] == 0, 
V44[0] == 0}, {V11, V12, V13, V14, V21, V22, V23, V24, V31, V32, 
V33, V34, V41, V42, V43, V44},{t, 0, 100},g0];
P2 = Plot[{Evaluate[1/2*(V11[t] + V22[t] - 2*V12[t])^(-1) /. s]}, {t, 
   0, 60}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Frame -> True,    
FrameLabel -> {Style["Time", Bold, 20], 
Style[" \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(q\)]\)", Bold, 20]}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20], 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0005], Thickness[0.008]}]
```

Comment: Can't find $g_0$ in your code for the DEs.

Comment: `g0` is the parameter inside `ParametricNDSolveValue` .

Comment: It's unclear what you want to plot "about g0". `P2=...`  is a time plot (which doesn't work)

Comment: @LouisB , sorry its not g0 , it is delc. Now please again see the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To plot the solution for a range of `delc`, make these changes to your code:

(1)  Remove `delc = 1;`  Leave `delc` undefined.  It will be your parameter.

(2)  Keep the `ParametricDSolveValue` command and its first argument, but change the other arguments to get

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[  ...   ,
    {1/2*(V11[t] + V22[t] - 2*V12[t])^(-1)}, {t, 0, 100}, delc];
```

Notice that the second argument is just the expression that we want to plot.  This is not the only way to do it, but it has its advantages.  Evaluate the code and plot the solution over the range of `delc` at `t = 60` like this

```
Plot[s[delc] /. t -> 60, {delc, 0, 2},
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {All, {0.545, .5475}},
 FrameLabel -> {Style["\[CapitalDelta]c", Bold, 20], 
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(q\)]\)", Bold, 20],
   Style["t = 60", Bold, 20]},
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20],
 GridLines->Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 1]

We can also plot the solution versus time for `delc = 1.25` like this

```
Plot[s[1.25], {t, 0, 100},
 PlotRange -> {All, {0, 15}}, Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Style["t", Bold, 20], 
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(q\)]\)", Bold, 20],
   Style["\[CapitalDelta]c = 1.25", Bold, 20]},
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20],
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 2]

**Edit to Plot an Average**

One way to average $S_q(\Delta c)$ for $\Delta c$ range from 0 to 2 is to simply evaluate `s[delc]` at various values of $\Delta c$ and find their mean.  Here is the (complete) code that accomplishes that:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
w1 = 1;
gma1 = 0.005;
n1 = 1;
gma2 = 0.005;
G1 = 0.005;

k1 = .1;
k2 = 0.1;
a1 = 0.07;
a2 = 0.58;
k0 = 0.1;
Q1 = 1.268;
del0 = 1;
N1 = 1;
ome = 1;
M1 = del0*(1 - Cos[ome*t]);

s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
    V11'[t] - V21[t]*w1 - V12[t]*w1 == 0,
    V12'[t] - V22[t]*w1 + w1*V11[t] + gma1*V12[t] -
      Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V13[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V14[t] == 0,
    V13'[t] - V23[t]*w1 + k1*V13[t] +
      Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V11[t] - (-G1*Q1 + delc)*V14[t] == 0,
    V14'[t] - V24[t]*w1 + k1*V14[t] -
      Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V11[t] - (G1*Q1 - delc)*V13[t] == 0,
    V21'[t] + V11[t]*w1 + gma1*V21[t] -
      Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V31[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V41[t] - w1*V22[t] == 0,
    V22'[t] + V12[t]*w1 + gma1*V22[t] -
      Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V32[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V42[t] +
      w1*V21[t] + gma1*V22[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V23[t] -
      Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V24[t] - gma2*(2*n1 + 1) == 0,
    V23'[t] + w1*V13[t] + gma1*V23[t] -
      Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V33[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V43[t] + k1*V23[t] +
      Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V21[t] - (-G1*Q1 + delc)*V24[t] == 0, 
    V24'[t] + V14[t]*w1 + gma1*V24[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V34[t] -
      Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V44[t] + k1*V24[t] -
      Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V21[t] - (G1*Q1 - delc)*V23[t] == 0,
    V31'[t] + k1*V31[t] + Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V11[t] -
      (-G1*Q1 + delc)*V41[t] - w1*V32[t] == 0,
    V32'[t] + k1*V32[t] + Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V12[t] -
      (-G1*Q1 + delc)*V42[t] + w1*V31[t] -
      Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V34[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V33[t] + gma1*V32[t] == 0,
    V33'[t] + k1*V33[t] + Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V13[t] -
      (-G1*Q1 + delc)*V43[t] + k1*V33[t] +
      Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V31[t] - (-G1*Q1 + delc)*V34[t] - k0 == 0,
    V34'[t] + k1*V34[t] + Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V14[t] -
      (-G1*Q1 + delc)*V44[t] + k1*V34[t] -
      Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V31[t] - (G1*Q1 - delc)*V33[t] == 0,
    V41'[t] + k1*V41[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V11[t] -
      (G1*Q1 - delc)*V31[t] - w1*V42[t] == 0,
    V42'[t] + k1*V42[t] + Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V12[t] -
      (G1*Q1 - delc)*V32[t] + w1*V41[t] -
      Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V44[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V43[t] + gma1*V42[t] == 0,
    V43'[t] + k1*V43[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V13[t] -
      (G1*Q1 - delc)*V33[t] + k1*V43[t] +
      Sqrt[2]*G1*a2*V41[t] - (-G1*Q1 + delc)*V44[t] == 0,
    V44'[t] + k1*V44[t] - Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V14[t] -
      (G1*Q1 - delc)*V34[t] + k1*V44[t] -
      Sqrt[2]*G1*a1*V41[t] - (G1*Q1 - delc)*V43[t] - k0 == 0,
    V11[0] == 1, V12[0] == 1, V13[0] == 0, V14[0] == 0,
    V21[0] == 0, V22[0] == 1, V23[0] == 0, V24[0] == 0,
    V31[0] == 0, V32[0] == 0, V33[0] == 0, V34[0] == 0,
    V41[0] == 0, V42[0] == 0, V43[0] == 0, V44[0] == 0},
   1/2*(V11[t] + V22[t] - 2*V12[t])^(-1), {t, 0, 100}, delc];

With[{avg = Mean@Table[s[dc], {dc, Subdivide[0, 2, 10]}]},
 Plot[avg, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 15}]]
```

[image]

Note that `Subdivide[0, 2, 10]` gives 11 evenly spaced sample points.  You can generate that same list using `Range[0, 2, 2/10]` or any other method you choose.  Eleven is enough points for the plot.  It turns out `s[delc]` gives practically the same function of $t$ for any value of `delc` in the interval from 0 to 2.

Comment: Please clarify 2nd point you mentioned above because its still not giving any plot.

Comment: Here's what I did:  Start with a fresh kernel.  Copy / paste the code from the question into a new notebook.  Remove the line containing `delc = 1;`.  Remove all the code beginning at `{V11, V12, V13 ..` to the end.  Copy / paste the second line of code from item (2) in answer.  Copy / paste the plot command from the answer.  Runs fine for me.  If you can't get it to work, maybe you should edit your question to show exactly what code you are using and what results or error message you are getting.

Comment: Thanks very much. its working now.

Comment: This plot that you have plotted, is for a particular value of time.i.e t=60, can you tell me how can i plot for t=30,10,20,70,.... and after that average of all plots?

Comment: `Plot[s[delc] /. t -> {10, 20, 30, 70}, {delc, 0, 2}]` gives a quick plot at the 4 times.  The "curves" look like straight lines because of the scale on the vertical axis.  I don't think you really want to average these curves.  Please consider asking a new question and tell us what you are trying to achieve, show or study, so we can provide answers that better hit the target.  You could average those curves, however, with `Plot[Mean[s[delc] /. t -> {10, 20, 30, 70}], {delc, 0, 2}]`

Comment: actually i am trying to find out a single line graph in which time also varies from t=0 to 100. The plot you have plotted is for a particular value of t=60 but in my case time is varying from t=0 to 100 as you show in the second graph. I want such a graph in which time also varies from 0 to 100 not for a particular value of time.

Comment: @vini Here is one way to plot an average of $S_q(\Delta c)$ for $\Delta c$ in the range of $[0, 2]$    `With[{avg = Mean@Table[s[dc], {dc, Subdivide[0, 2, 10]}]},
 Plot[avg, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 15}]]`

Comment: but it is showing error like; "Iterator {dc,Subdivide[0,2,10]} does not have appropriate bounds. "

Comment: It works fine for me.  Please tell me exactly what you did to get the message.  First, you started with a fresh kernel, yes?  Then you executed your code, through the `s = ParametricNDSolveValue[ ... ]` statement.  Then what code did you execute?  You can edit your question to include the new code that is producing the error message.  Please make sure that people can reproduce the problem by cut / pasting the code from your question into an empty notebook (with a fresh kernel).

Comment: Yes, i started with fresh kernel. Then s = ParametricNDSolveValue[  ...   ,
    {1/2*(V11[t] + V22[t] - 2*V12[t])^(-1)}, {t, 0, 100}, delc]; After this code i write ,         With[{avg = Mean@Table[s[dc], {dc, Subdivide[0, 2, 10]}]}, Plot[avg, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> {0, 15}]]

Comment: I will modify my answer to show exact working code.

Comment: i don't know why my Mathematica is showing error for this code. I have copy and paste your edited code in a fresh kernel but it is showing error. Iterator {delc,Subdivide[0,2,10]} does not have appropriate bounds. >>

Comment: Look at my last paragraph.  Replace `Subdivide[  ]` with some other code that generates values of `delc`.  What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: Mathmatica 9.0.1.0

Comment: `Subdivide` was introduced in Mathematica 10.1 (March 2015).  Mathematica 9 should show it with blue color, which indicates Mathematica 9 does not have a definition for `Subdivide`.  Functions, variables, etc that have definitions are shown in black.   The color is a big clue that we use as a "sanity check".  If something looks like it has the wrong color, we always want to know why.

Comment: Can we plot this in 3D where x axis for delc, y-axis for Sq and z-axis for 't'

Comment: Please read your documentation for `Plot3D`.  After you have looked at the syntax and examples, try something like `Plot3D[ s[dc], {dc, 0, 2}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotPoints -> {10, 500} ]`.  If you have trouble with it, start a new question in this forum and show us what you have tried.  Also, in your new question remind us that you are using version 9.